# How to access current_user from a Doorkeeper authenticated session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, doorkeeper

I have a [rails app](//github.com/wholcomb/smoke_tracker_rails) that I am attempting to sync with an [android app](https://github.com/wholcomb/smoke_tracker). I've successfully set up [authentication](https://github.com/wholcomb/smoke_tracker/blob/add-syncadapter/src/com/synaptian/smoketracker/habits/authenticator/AuthenticatorActivity.java) using [Doorkeeper](https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper) as the server and [Oltu](http://oltu.apache.org) as the client.

My app tracks habits which exist as per-user lists. My index method in the habits controller is:

```
def index
  @habits = current_user.habits
end
```

When authenticating via Devise this method works, when using Doorkeeper `current_user` is `nil`.

Answer (score 10):

From [Doorkeeper's README](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper#authenticated-resource-owner) ...

#### Authenticated resource owner

If you want to return data based on the current resource owner, in other
words, the access token owner, you may want to define a method in your
controller that returns the resource owner instance:

```
class Api::V1::CredentialsController < Api::V1::ApiController
  before_action :doorkeeper_authorize!
  respond_to    :json

  # GET /me.json
  def me
    respond_with current_resource_owner
  end

  private

  # Find the user that owns the access token
  def current_resource_owner
    User.find(doorkeeper_token.resource_owner_id) if doorkeeper_token
  end
end
```

In this example, we're returning the credentials (`me.json`) of the access
token owner.

Answer (score 9):

I would override current_user in your base API controller, something like:

```
private

def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(doorkeeper_token[:resource_owner_id])
end
```

Answer (score 9):

I have an API that needed to allow authentication via Doorkeeper OR Devise.  The following solution allows the main application to use the same endpoints that Oauth clients would use and share the current_user method.

```
before_action :doorkeeper_authorize!, unless: :user_signed_in?

def current_user
  @current_user ||= if doorkeeper_token
                      User.find(doorkeeper_token.resource_owner_id)
                    else
                      warden.authenticate(scope: :user)
                    end
end
```

Comment: You are a genius! I was looking for such a beautiful solution (as I wanted to do the exact same thing as you did: use my API with Doorkeeper OR Devise)! Thanks a lot for sharing it!

Comment: This should be marked as the right answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the right method or not, but a solution is to do:

```
def index
  user = current_user
  user ||= User.find(doorkeeper_token[:resource_owner_id]) if doorkeeper_token
  @habits = user.habits
end
```

You can't assign to `current_user` or it will set it to `nil`.